# Attempting to sort by lastname from a name object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

I have the following block:

```
sortedNameArray = [nameArray  sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

That I use to take an array of Strings and alphabetize them. Now what I want to do is get it to alphabetize an array of Name objects(an object with a NSString firstName and a NSString lastName) by looking at the last name attribute then alphabetizing the objects by its lastName attribute. Here is an example of a Name object:

```
  Name *bobSmith = [[Name alloc] init];
[bobSmith setFirstName:@"Bob"];
[bobSmith setLastName:@"Smith"]; // this is what I want to alphabetize it by
```

I have tried:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [nameArray count]; i++){
sortedNameArray = [[nameArray[i] getLastName]  sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
}
```

but this obviously does not work. How can I get this method to alphabetize an array of objects by looking at one of it's string attributes.... ie taking an array of Name objects, looking at their last name (an NSString) and alphabetizing the objects according to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
sortedNameArray = [nameArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 lastName] compare:[obj2 lastName]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sortDescriptors to alphabetise an array of Name objects

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSArray *sortedArray = [nameArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

nameArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
```

I pulled the code from Sort Descriptor Programming Topics. Also, Key-Value Coding comes into play, in that sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: will send a valueForKey: to each element in myArray, and then use standard comparators to sort the returned values.